# How to check if an AD username is already used

Tags: active-directory, powershell

Thank you in advance for your help. I found something related at the following link but was unable to find the solution I was looking for through here. [Check existance of domain accounts with Powershell script](https://serverfault.com/questions/138598/check-existance-of-domain-accounts-with-powershell-script)

What I am trying to do is take usernames from a list that is already generated into a CSV file from another script I am running.

Once I have these usernames (sAMAccountname) I want to check if that username is already being used. If it is I want it to be shown, perhaps via Echo, and then to continue checking the other names. If it's not then it should simply continue checking other names.

Here is what I have up to now. ( Keep in mind I am a complete Powershell novice and I am only doing this out of absolute need )

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Continue
$UserCSV = import-csv "\\fs1\DisasterRecovery\Source Controlled Items\WindowsPowerShell\Test scripts\Import Production Users\Users.csv"
$UserList = $UserCSV.sAMAccountname
foreach($User in $UserList)
{
if (Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountname -eq $User} ) {
  # Exists
  #echo Already Exists
} else {
  SilentlyContinue
}
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Powershell 3 or better, there is no need for `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`. PS will automatically load the module for you as soon as you use a cmdlet from that module.  Use `$PSVersionTable` to know for sure, but I think you are using PS 3 or better because you appear to use an automatic foreach in your code, and automatic foreach didn't become available until PS 3.

Furthermore, there's no point in continuing if the module fails to load, since it is critical to the rest of the script, so the `-ErrorAction Continue` doesn't make sense either. I'd strike the entire first line.

Line two where you Import-CSV is OK. The `$UserList` variable seems superfluous.  From there I'd probably do something like this:

```
$UserCSV = Import-Csv C:\Users\Administrator\test.csv
Foreach ($User in $UserCSV)
{
    Try
    {
        # Use "EA Stop" to ensure the exception is caught.
        $U = Get-ADUser $User.sAMAccountName -ErrorAction Stop 
        Write-Host "$($User.SamAccountName) is already in use."
    }
    Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException]
    {
        # The user was not found!
        Write-Warning "$($User.SamAccountName) was not found in this domain!"
    }
    Catch
    {
        # Some other terrible error occured!
        Write-Error "OHSHI"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I ended up using this and modifying it slightly to make it precisely what my team needed. This helped me get a better understanding of PowerShell and it's structure, greatly appreciate. If you happen to have the time and will could you explain what the Catch [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADIdentityNotFoundException] portion is doing? Is that just something that is meant to work with Get-ADUser by design for precisely these situations? Thanks again for all of your efforts.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tested this, but the structure would be more like:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory -ErrorAction Continue
$UserCSV = import-csv "\\fs1\DisasterRecovery\Source Controlled Items\WindowsPowerShell\Test scripts\Import Production Users\Users.csv"

foreach($row in $UserCSV)
{
    $userAccount = Get-ADUser -Filter {sAMAccountname -eq $row.sAMAccountname}

    if ($userAccount) {
        Write-Host "User $($row.sAMAccountname) exists"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to test for the existence of the sAMAccountname not only for users, groups can also have the same sAMAccountname.
This can be done by using `Get-ADObject`
This way there is no exception thrown, but you can throw one yourself.

```
$sAMAccountname = "TestToTest"

if(@(Get-ADObject -Filter { sAMAccountname -eq $sAMAccountname }).Count -ge 1){
    Write-Host "$sAMAccountname exsists"
}else{
    Write-Host "$sAMAccountname doesn't exsist"
}
```